# Where can I get http response code from HttpClient returned from Twitter search?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am making a call to Twitter search and getting JSON response.  My understanding is that if the twitter request limit is exceeded this will be reported in HttpResponse code. How can I obtain the response code from the HttpClient classes after the request is made?

Also does anyone know if this is in fact how twitter reports the rate limit exceeded?

```
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
            import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
            import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
            import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl); 
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = null;
    try{
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
                    // How can I get HTTP response code?
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: your response string is null when you run this?

Comment: No but it will not contain the HTTP response code. It contains a String of data.

Comment: check the post below, is promising

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a response handler at all – you can get the status code from a plain `HttpResponse` instance using `HttpResponse#getStatusLine()`:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl); 
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Recommended reading:

- [`HttpResponse`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html)
- [`StatusLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html)

---

**N.B.** when [`BasicResponseHandler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html) returns a `String` instead of throwing an exception, that implies the response code was a `2xx` (that is, `200 <= code < 300`).